# Does jTDS JDBC 1.3.1 driver support Java 8 and SQL Server 2015 and up?

Tags: linux, jdbc, windows-authentication, jtds

I would like to know whether JDBC 1.3.1 driver of jTDS support java 8 and later versions of SQL server.

I need to use Windows Authentication both for Linux and Windows servers. There are others JDBC drivers for that?

My question born because the JDBC´s latest version (1.3.1) of jTDS was in 2013.

Comment: You can use the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver for that. See https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel for your response. Microsoft Server JDBC driver does also work for windows authentication from a Linux machine? Because since I know it only works from Windows machine. I am wrong?  ... the key point is windows authentication mode from Linux.

Comment: Yes it does using Kerberos, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-kerberos-integrated-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, Kerberos authentication requires a Kerberos server. It is a different standard than native Windows authentication.

Comment: Kerberos is an authentication protocol, and it is part of Microsoft Active Directory, and has been at least since Windows Server 2000 (maybe even earlier).

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-operations-studio/enable-kerberos

Comment: ok. thank you @MarkRotteveel